# About Installation and format

Tags: hard-drive, format

I am switching from windows 10 to ubuntu. So, I want to know that during ubuntu installation. The installer will format my whole hard drive or only instaling drive. 
Please give reply fast I am waiting

Answer (score 1):

The installer will ask you how you want your hard drive partitioned. You can choose to install Ubuntu alongside Windows or format the entire drive

[image: Installer]